# creating restricted anonymous survey

Tags: javascript, php

I know this will involve javascript and php.
I am trying to make a survey for a two week summer camp I'm running.
I need to limit the responses to the individuals involved (need to not be public), but I also need the individual responses to be anonymous within that scope. I would prefer it be more of a one time use individual access code I can distribute over email. I'm not sure where to start for the coding on this.

On a related note, how would I go about anonymously (or at least semi-anonymously) distribute the access codes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Going with your access code approach. I will suggest you create a database and create a table in the database to hold access codes. Create another table to hold a list of all members, including their email addresses.

Then build the form with your desired form fields. One of the form fields should hold the member's input for access code. During form processing validate that the access code exists and you can either have the form data mailed to you or stored in another table in your database.

To preserve anonymity while distributing the keys, create a simple php script that will traverse through the members table and generate an access code for each member and mail the code to the member's email address. Each code generated should be stored in the table holding the access codes.

As long as you don't check the server's mail queue, you won't see what code is being sent to what email.

Hope this suggestion helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a start on the coding, or perhaps even an actual solution. A couple of years ago, I had to put together a survey system for a professor who wanted to survey his students. You can download it here: http://clicketyhome.com/survey/ It's free. It's not a product. It's PHP with just a few lines of Javascript.

It's also not private. You'll have to do that feature separately. For your low-stakes purposes, I'd suggest you just password the directory. What security issues do you expect? People taking the survey 100 times to throw the totals off?